# How to get the screen coordinates of the Picture (a Shape) placed over an excel cell in Excel 2007/2010

Tags: excel, image

I'm writing an application, where i've 30 rows, 1 column with data.
Each cell in the 30 rows has a picture object placed over it (it means an Excel shape).
If i try to get the screen position for the picture objects, that are in the visible range, then i'm able to get  the screen co-ordinates correctly Say for example for the cells `A1..A10`.

But when i try to get the screen coordinates for the pictures that are NOT in the visible range, the values returned are not correct.

Because if i apply `ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(X, Y)` for the calculated X and Y screen coordinates, the API is returning null.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that everything you're saying would make sense - the x & y coordinates for anything have to be on screen, because that is what determines their coordinates!

For example, the most upper and left coordinate value would be (0,0), while (in my case) the lowermost right value would be (1920,1080) because my screen is 1920 x 1080. If an object, or point, or whatever appears off-screen, the points will have a null value likely because Excel is only measuring coordinates within the visible range of the screen. Now, perhaps there is a way to circumvent this and say that maybe a point in question in row 100 has a coordinate value of (10, 3000) but who knows.

It is likely that the problem you are currently having is one that I am having - how do you detect when a mouse moves over a specific object on-screen? It seems like you would need a program that continually re-measures the coordinates of all on-screen objects and passes those coordinates to whatever program you need them in. A picture or cell may have a certain xy position, but if the user scrolls up, down, left, or right, or zooms in or out, that object will have moved in relation to the edges of the screen, and thus have different coordinates. If you know of an API call to do the above, I would certainly like to hear it.

I know I haven't fully answered your question but I hope this helps.